# How to compute the $n^{th}$ partial sum of a series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity, telescopic-series

Compute explicitly $S_n(x)$, the $n^{th}$ partial sum of the series

$$\sum_{k=1}^∞ \frac{x\left[-1+4k(k+1)x^2\right]}{(1+4k^2x^2)(1+4(k+1)^2x^2)}$$

then compute the sum $S(x)$ of the infnite series, and prove that, for $a > 0$, the
series is not uniformly convergent on $(a, a)$, but is uniformly convergent on
$(a, ∞)$

My attempt:

$$S_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^∞ \frac?{1+4k^2x^2} - \frac?{1+4(k+1)^2x^2}$$  which is a telescoping series.

And then, having formed $S_n(x)$, I find $S(x)$ = $\lim_{n→∞} S_n(x)$.

Finally, I find $M_n = \sup|S_n(x) - S(x)|$ and if $\lim_{n→∞} M_n$ = $0$, then it converges uniformly. My problem is in the first step. I don't know how to compute $S_n(x)$ explicitly.help please?
[This is my attempt for partial fraction decomposition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWKpL.jpg)

Comment: Do you know how to do partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: @Clayton yes I do

Comment: When you tried it here, did anything go wrong?

Comment: @Clayton I'm gonna try it now and let you know

Comment: @Clayton I ended up getting A=B, I chose B=1 so A=1, where A and B are the question marks in the above partial sum. Is it correct?

Comment: You need to show your steps. It does not look correct to me.

Comment: @Clayton I don't know how to get it, please help me compute $S_n(x)$

Comment: I don’t know how you have done your partial fractions. How can I help without seeing?

Comment: @Clayton Look at the link in the question. I posted my attempt

Comment: The numerators in a partial fraction decomposition have to have a degree one less than the denominators, so the numerator of the first fraction should be $dx+e$ and the second $fx+g$.  That gives you enough parameters.  It looks to me like $e=g=0$ because the denominators have only even powers of $x$ and the numerators only odd.

Comment: Maybe $a=kx$ and $b=a+x$ work.

Comment: @RMWGNE96: Wouldn't that mean $b=(k+1)x$?

Comment: Yes, so $a=kx$ and $b=(k+1)x$.

Comment: Ross is correct; you need the numerators of each fraction to be $Ax+B$ and $Cx+D$, respectively (or anything equivalent). Once you have these numerators, you can explicitly solve for $A,B,C$, and $D$ and then you'll hopefully be on your way to solving the problem.

Comment: Okay, thank you guys! Now I got it! But now, how can I find $lim_{n →∞}S_n(x)$? The expression doesn't contain n

Comment: @RossMillikan I got the same answer: e = g = 0, but I'm not able to find d and f. Any help?

Comment: $S_n$ comes from replacing the upper limit of the sum with $n$

Comment: @RossMillikan You mean replacing k with n?

Comment: No, replacing the upper $\infty$ with $n$.  That gives you the sum with $n$ terms.  Then the sum telescopes.  The second term of $k$ cancels with the first term of $k+1$, leaving only the first term of $k=0$ and the second term of $k=n$.  The second term goes to zero, so the infinite sum is just the first term

Comment: @RossMillikan then what would be the new series? I don't understand how replacing n with infinity can help me in calculating the limit of $S_n(x)$

Comment: Your expression for $S_n(x)$ should just be the sum from $k=1$ to $k=n$.  Then you will take the limit as $n \to \infty$.  That is really what we mean when we say the sum goes to infinity.

Comment: It is like the famous $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}=1$.  To really prove that, you say $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n2^{-k}=1-2^{-n}$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}S_n=1$.  You are to do the same thing here.

Comment: @RossMillikan I got the lim of $S_n$ = $0$

Comment: No because the first term in $k=1$ survives, so the sum is $\frac 4{1+x^2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments we are trying to do a partial fraction decomposition$$\frac{x\left[-1+4k(k+1)x^2\right]}{(1+4k^2x^2)(1+4(k+1)^2x^2)}=\frac{ax+b}{1+4k^2x^2} - \frac{cx+d}{1+4(k+1)^2x^2}\\=\frac{(ax+b)(1+4(k+1)^2x^2)-(cx+d)(1+4k^2x^2)}{(1+4k^2x^2)(1+4(k+1)^2x^2)}\\
-x+4k(k+1)x^3=(ax+b)(1+4(k+1)^2x^2)-(cx+d)(1+4k^2x^2)\\b+d=0\\4(k+1)^2b+4k^2d=0\\b=d=0\\a-c=-1\\4(k+1)^2a-4k^2c=4k(k+1)\\4(k+1)^2a-4k^2(a+1)=4k(k+1)\\(2k+1)a-4k^2=4k(k+1)\\a=\frac {8k^2+4k}{2k+1}\\a=4k\\c=4k+1$$